# What's the easiest way to shrink and move an entire turtle drawing?

Tags: python

I'm messing around with turtle and I drew something but I want to be able to scale down it's size and put it in a different part of the screen.

For example let's say you have a stickman made up of five rectangles and one circle as the head, when drawing the stickman I had to give the x and y positions for each rectangle and also the length/width of each one but now it's too big and I want the entire stickman smaller.

Is there a way to easily scale down the stickman I already drew? and also be able to assign the entire object different x/y cords as a whole so I can place him somewhere else?

Let me know if anyone can help, I'm trying to just make a simple stick man game and this is really crucial to know so sorry if it's a very basic question.

Comment: Why don't you draw the stickman where you need it, at the scale you need it at? I don't think the Python turtle allows you to cut and paste a scaled version. You might be able to change the zoom of the view so that it *appears* to have scaled and moved, but that wouldn't actually change any of the sizes or positions.

Comment: Turtle graphics was designed to teach students logic (see [Logo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language))), not do sophisticated graphics — so I suggest that you use a graphics library designed other purposes instead of beating your head trying to use it to do things it was never designed for.